# why am i getting close option only for my questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, privileges

Why am I getting option "close" for my questions?

[image: pic with close option for my question]

Is this an new feature or an bug? is it only appearing for me?

Why do I get a "close" option for my questions? does this mean the user who posted the question can cast his vote to close his/her question?

Comment: @Bart i failed to check faq :( and i requested moderator to remove this foolish question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation). After 250 points you can vote to close your own questions:

```
250  Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions
```

On the image you have around 350 points, so you have probably recently passed this limit